# How to force require.js to load all resources from one directory

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I have typescript generating a javascript file that starts with this line:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery", "chart.js", "./util"], function (require, exports, $, chart, util_1) {
```

I want all of those dependencies to be loaded from `/static/XXX.js`, however `require.js` fires off the following requests:

```
/static/initialscript.js (I put the abstract path in data-main)
/static/jquery.js (exactly what I want)
/html/chart.js (uses relative path to HTML file - ERROR)
/html/util (uses relative path to HTML and doesn't append .js - ERROR)
```

I tried to set the base path in the `require.js` configuration, however this didn't change anything.

How can I force `require.js` to load all dependencies from the `/static/` folder on my webserver?

**Update:**

This is the HTML code I use to load the script:

```html
<script data-main="/static/initialscript.js" src="/static/require.js"></script>
```

I tried the above with both no configuration and a configuration that I created before the above line:

```
<script>
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/static/',
    paths: {
        'chart.js': '/static/chart.js'
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1711

Comment: Please include in the question the RequireJS configuration you are using, and the HTML you use to load RequireJS and your modules. (Just the `script` elements, in the same order as they appear in your HTML should be enough.) Loading `"./util"` should not be an issue, but a bad configuration could mess it up.

Comment: @Louis please see my edit